# NodeJS async/await and function call

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, pg-promise

I'm running `NodeJS` with `pg-promise` for accessing my `PostgreSQL`.

This is my test, which fails with `undefined`:

```
function a() {
  pgPromise.one('SELECT 1')
  .then(row => {
     return row;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

console.log(a());
```

I asume it fails with `undefined` because it's running asyncronized.

I've tried to optimize with:

```
async function a() {
  var output = null;
  await pgPromise.one('SELECT 1')
  .then(row => {
     output = row;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });

  return output;
}

console.log(a());
```

But that simply gives me:

```
[2018-09-13 08:37:09.521] [LOG]   Promise { <pending> }
```

Comment: You call `console.log(a())` with a function that does not return anything. What did you expect? Of course it will print `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must `await` for the result, so that you don't get the promise but its result once it's solved:

```
console.log(await a());
```

But your code is way too complicated. Your `a` function makes no real sense.

Change

```
async function a() {
  var output = null;
  await pgPromise.one('SELECT 1')
  .then(row => {
     output = row;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });

  return output;
}
```

to

```
async function a() {
  try {
      return await pgPromise.one('SELECT 1')
  } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
  }
}
```

If you're getting a syntax error on the `await`, it probably means you're not in an `async` function. A typical case in node is when you're at the root. The simplest solution is to wrap it in an `async` function:

```
;(async function(){
    console.log(await a());
})();
```

Comment: I'm getting `console.log(await a());
            ^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: Seems to work, but wow, seems like quite a hack to wrap a pg-promise inside a global function.

Comment: async function a() {
  try {
      return await pgPromise.one('SELECT 1')
  } catch error) {
      console.log(error);
  }
}

Comment: @AlfredBalle you only need that at the root. For the rest everything is supposed to be either async or not and you know it. For a REPL application I always launch node with a modifier: `node --experimental-repl-await myapp.js`

Comment: @AlfredBalle It's better for you to first understand how asynchronous code work before using async/await. Unless you are very comfortable with wrapping your entire code inside a SINGLE global function. (note: you may find doing multiple global function wrapper to also not work as you expect. It MUST be a single global function wrapper)

Comment: It's simply because I need to run the function `a` many places in my code, which I would like to write it only once.

Comment: if you need it at many places, it's always in asynchronous contexts, so in functions which are already async (or you return it as a promise)

Answer (score 1):

`async functions` return a Promise, so you need to await it or use `.then()` in order to get the result.

Remember that `await` can only be used inside an `async function` so you need to change the structure of your code.

I recommend you check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and also more information asynchronous programming in Javascript.

Keeping your first code like that, it could be fixed like this (still is a bit weird in my opinion):

```
function a() {
  return pgPromise.one('SELECT 1')
  .then(row => {
     return row;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

a().then(console.log);
```

If you want to go with async/await, this example could be good for learning purposes:

```
async function a() {
  const row = await pgPromise.one('SELECT 1');
  return row;
}

a().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

In this case the error handling is being done outside the function, in the caller side (it could be done inside through try/catch, it depends on the use case).